# c++ function returning a macaddress as a string

Tags: function, arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a function that should return a string in c++. Something like this:

```
#include <string>

String printmac(uint8_t *mac){
    Serial.println("Entering printmac");
    //Serial.printf("%X", &mac); //test
    String s1 = "";                     
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {  
        sprintf(s1, "%02X", mac[i]);
        if (i<5){s1=+":";}
    }
    return s1;
}

Serial.printf("%s\n", printmac(info->sourceaddr));
```

Where info->sourceaddr is a pointer of the type uint_8.
The goal is to print something like 56:A5:12:E3:72:11 to serial.

I get "Compilation error: cannot convert 'String' to 'char*'" from "sprintf(s1, "%02X", mac[i]);"

How can I do this?

Thanx!

I have tried all sorts of combinations, but not found the right.

Comment: `Serial` and `String` — what are these? Where are they defined? If you are using some specific library which defines these, please clarify! Might be very important to answer properly.

Comment: Those come from the Arduino SDK. I updated the tags.

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> `int sprintf( char* buffer, const char* format, ... );`

Your first argument to `sprint` is *not* a `char*` but a `String` which is why it fails to compile.

You could create a temporary buffer that you `sprintf` into and when done, construct a `String` from it. Here's an example of how to join the values in a `uint8_t[]` over a `char`, like `:` (colon):

```cpp
template<unsigned N>
String HexJoin(const uint8_t(&mac)[N], char ch = ':') {
    char buf[N * 3];

    sprintf(buf, "%02X", mac[0]);
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        sprintf(buf + (i * 3) - 1, "%c%02X", ch, mac[i]);
    }

    return buf;  // or  return String(buf);
}
```

Example usage:

```cpp
Serial.print(HexJoin(info->sourceaddr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help,
I tried Breno's idea and finally wrote this:

```
> String printmac(uint8_t *mac){
>     char buffer[18];  //Create a char-array like 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF0' (Null terminated)
>     for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {sprintf(buffer + (i*3), "%02X:", mac[i]);}
>     buffer[17] = '\0';  //Removing trailing ':' and null terminating the char array
>     return String(buffer); }
```

I should have mention that I am writing it in Arduino IDE and implementing it on an ESP8266 wifi module, but you worked that out anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You're having trouble because sprintf() is designed to work with C-style strings (which are arrays of characters), but you're trying to use it with an Arduino String object.

Also, the += operator in s1=+":"; is wrong; it should be +=.

To fix the code, you can use a mix of C-style string operations and then convert the result to an Arduino String. Here's how you can modify the printmac() function to get the output you want:

In the Arduino envoriment you can try

```
#include String printmac(uint8_t *mac) {
Serial.println("Entering printmac");
char buffer[18]; // Enough space for MAC address string (17 characters + null terminator)
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    // Append each byte of the MAC address to buffer
    sprintf(buffer + (i * 3), "%02X:", mac[i]);
}
buffer[17] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
buffer[16] = '\0'; // Remove the trailing ':'
return String(buffer);
```

}

// Usage:
// Serial.printf("%s\n", printmac(info->sourceaddr).c_str());

Comment: `sprintf(buffer + (i * 3), "%02X:", mac[i]);` has UB when `i == 5`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried Breno's idea and finally wrote this:

> String printmac(uint8_t *mac){
>     char buffer[18];  //Create a char-array like 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF0' (Null terminated)
>     for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {sprintf(buffer + (i*3), "%02X:", mac[i]);}
>     buffer[17] = '\0';  //Removing trailing ':' and null terminating the char array
>     return String(buffer); }

I should have mention that I am writing it in Arduino IDE and implementing it on an ESP8266 wifi module, but you worked that out anyway.